# Media player taking too much time to prepare and start

Tags: android, url, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I want to play Mp3 URL, i have used Media player for it. it is working but it's taking too much time to be prepare and start, i have referred to many sites but yet i had not got any satisfied solution.

I have stuck into this, So please guys help to solve it!!

My code look like as below

```
try {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource(mArrayList.get(0).MUSIC_URL);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
            seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
            seekUpdation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: MUSIC_URL is having a which url is it from your device storage can you please share the Url

Comment: you can take any MP3 url, like http://vprbbc.streamguys.net/vprbbc24.mp3

Comment: I think that is not case of coding problem because normally when you are playing audio and video file from any host it will first store it in to a buffer and then after when buffer is prepare then after it will start accessing a data from buffer so if your internet connection speed is slow it take some time to process this. But if your internet connection speed is fast then it will not taking so much time

Comment: you meant first i have to store MP3 audio and after that will play?

Comment: No. read my post again.I said that when you directly play any audio or video file it will always take some time to buffered and play like youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
   mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

if you see the doc, explanation will be like this

```
 * Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously.
 *
 * After setting the datasource and the display surface, you need to either
 * call prepare() or prepareAsync(). For streams, you should call prepareAsync(),
 * which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been
 * buffered.
```

In your case you are streaming data, so need to use *prepareAsync()*

Hope it helps